# How do I read long lines from a text file in C++?

Tags: c++

I am using the following code for reading lines from a text-file. What is the best method for handling the case where the line is greater than the limit SIZE_MAX_LINE?

```
void TextFileReader::read(string inFilename)
{
    ifstream xInFile(inFilename.c_str());
    if(!xInFile){
        return;
    }

    char acLine[SIZE_MAX_LINE + 1];

    while(xInFile){
        xInFile.getline(acLine, SIZE_MAX_LINE);
        if(xInFile){
            m_sStream.append(acLine); //Appending read line to string
        }
    }

    xInFile.close();
}
```

Comment: i actually wanted to know how to handle the eofbit and failbit set by the function

Comment: If you use std::strings you don't need to test the size limit

Comment: what will the size of one read line be then?

Comment: Whatever size the read line has. `std::string` expands dynamically according to the needs at runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `istream::getline()`. It deals with naked character buffers and is therefor prone to errors. Better use `std::getline(std::istream&,std::string&, char='\n')` from the `<string>` header:

```
std::string line;

while(std::getline(xInFile, line)) {
    m_sStream.append(line);
    m_sStream.append('\n'); // getline() consumes '\n'
}
```

Comment: How about this?

 istream_iterator<string> cursor( xInFile );
 istream_iterator<string> endmarker;

 while( cursor!= endmarker) {
  m_sStream.append(*cursor);
  cursor++;
 }

Comment: @sonofdelphi: IIUC, this will read _words_, not _lines_ (where a "word" is anything delimited by whitespace). In order for it to read lines, you would have to instantiate `std::istream_iterator` with a type that reads lines, instead of words. It shouldn't be to hard to come up with such a type, but there is none in the std lib.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using C++ and iostream already, why not use `std::string`'s [`getline` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)?

```
std::string acLine;
while(xInFile){
    std::getline(xInFile, acLine);
    // etc.
}
```

---

And, use `xInFile.good()` to ensure `eofbit` and `badbit` and `failbit` are *not* set.

Comment: I'd just do  "while( std::getline( xInFile, acLine ) ) {}"

Comment: Kenny, when input fails, this will attempt to process old data in the `// etc.` part. (If the string was local to the function, it would at least be an empty string.) Better use Nikko's idiom. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910836/how-do-i-read-long-lines-from-a-text-file-in-c/2911350#2911350).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [free function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) in string, you don't have to pass a max length.  It also the uses C++ string type.