# How to load only certain lines from a text file depending on how they start in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, load

I have some data in a file, as shown below:

> [$GPGSA,A,3,28,09,26,15,08,05,21,24,07,,,,1.6,1.0,1.3*3A,
>   $GPRMC,151018.000,A,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,0.11,104.71,210214,,*14,
>   $GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72,
>   $GPGSA,A,3,28,09,26,15,08,05,21,24,07,,,,1.6,1.0,1.3*3A,
>   $GPGSV,3,1,12,26,80,302,44,09,55,063,40,05,53,191,39,08,51,059,37*79,
>   $GPGSV,3,2,12,28,43,112,34,15,40,284,42,21,18,305,33,07,18,057,27*7E,

The file contains many thousands of lines and each line starts with a certain tag which holds certain data.

I only need the lines that start with $GPGGA and $GPGSV.

How can I load in only these lines into a linked list type structure and keep their order without having to load in the other lines which I do not need?

Here is some of my code.. The details of the fscanf are unknown yet.
All I know what to do is to load in a file lines by line into a linked list.

```
 if ((head)==NULL){
     (head) = malloc(sizeof(GPSList));
     current = (head);
    }else{
        while(current->next!=NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
    }



 while( fscanf(fa,"", ) != EOF) {//format will be done later
        // Create new ship here.
        strcpy(current->dataGPS.Latitude, Latitude);
        strcpy(current->dataGPS.Longitude, Longitude);

        current->dataGPS.Time = Time;
        current->dataGPS.NumSat = NumSat;
        current->dataGPS.SNR =SNR;




        GPSList *next = malloc(sizeof(GPSList));
        current->next = next;
        current = next;
```

Comment: Why `(head) = ...` instead of `head = ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ code:

```
std::string line;

while(std::getline(xInFile, line)) {
    // Check if a line starts with what you need

    if(std::regex_match(line, "/^(?:(?:\$GPGGA)|(?:\$GPGSV)).*$/")) {
        // Use the line. For instance, put it to some array.
    };
}
```

How to read a file line by line: [How do I read long lines from a text file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910836/how-do-i-read-long-lines-from-a-text-file-in-c)

More on regular expressions: [Regular-Expressions.info - Regex Tutorial, Examples and Reference - Regexp Patterns](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

More on std::regex_match(): [std::regex_match - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)

More on std::getline(): [std::getline - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: So what exactly does the ---while(std::getline(xInFile, line)) { -- Do?

Comment: It gets the lines from your file one by one until the file ends.

Comment: @NJD, the first link in my answer gives some explanation of it. Actually, it is where I took it from.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file. Loop over the lines in the file. Read each line in. If it starts with `$GPGGA` or `$GPGSV`, add it to the linked list type structure. Otherwise, continue to the next line. When you reach the end of the file, you're done.

Comment: All I have done before is load in each line of a file.. with all lines being of the same format for that was easy. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Which part don't you know how to do? Post your code. (I can't help you tell if a string begins with particular characters without knowing what language you're using, what form you have the string in, and so on. Maybe `strncmp` is what you want, maybe `string::find`. A vague question will not have a specific answer.)